# import module by name or by path

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-modules, lit-element

I'm not clear with the difference between importing a js module by name (like the common react or polymer lit-element usage) or by path (aka npm modules).
What's the difference and why there is a difference in the first place?
Why can't I import `lit-element` using:

`import { LitElement, html } from 'lit-element'`

like a normal npm module and use it in the browser without getting this error: `Failed to resolve module specifier. Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".`?

Comment: Please provide the exact way you are trying to import.  If you are using a browser, you have to use a relative path `/, ./, ../` or a fully qualified path `https://example.com/module/index.js`.  Webpack and other loaders use their own rules that don't follow that spec.

Comment: I'm not talking about bundler. I'm talking about standard modern browsers. You can't import `lit-element` in a browser without a bundler (or without their CLI) because the module is imported "by name". I'm trying to import this `import { LitElement, html } from 'lit-element'`

Answer (score 1):

Using ES6 module syntax in the browser is currently only supported with paths as specifiers  because it's not yet clear how bare specifiers are going to get resolved to URLs.

- Other specifiers are reserved for future-use, such as importing built-in modules.
- The nodejs module resolution algorithm cannot be replicated because it requires testing for file existence, which is reasonable locally but not sensible over HTTP - and of course there's no `node_modules` folder anywhere.
- Work is ongoing for allowing more elaborate solutions, e.g. [module loaders](https://github.com/whatwg/loader/) or [import maps](https://github.com/WICG/import-maps). Paths were just the minimal viable solution that could be released to the public, while guaranteeing forward-compatibility.

Sources: [[1]](https://jakearchibald.com/2017/es-modules-in-browsers/), [[2]](https://medium.com/@dmnsgn/es-modules-in-the-browser-almost-now-3638ffafdc68), [[3]](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2018/03/es-modules-a-cartoon-deep-dive/)

Comment: I will take a look at the sources, but in the meanwhile, you're talking about remote URLs. This doesn't explain why some modules (such as lit-element) cannot be imported in-browser (with ANY syntax) even if they are installed locally. And most of all why we are here differentiating import "by path" or "by name" when I think the difference it's on how the module are exported.

Comment: @alfredopacino "*even if they are installed locally*" - they are not installed locally in the browser. And the browser doesn't know (and doesn't care) whether they are installed locally at the server or build environment.

Comment: Let me be clear about my doubt: I see your point, but either is valid for all modules (which is not true) or some modules (like lit-element) are somehow different. The question: what's the difference?

Comment: @alfredopacino Why do you think that some modules are special?

Comment: @alfredopacino If you mean the first one: there is no difference about how the modules are exported. It's all about the browser finding the module code from the specifier that is used in the `import` clause.

Comment: no I meant the last one. If there is no difference, how can I use `lit-element` in browser without preprocessing?

Comment: @alfredopacino You cannot `import 'lit-element'` because the browser cannot resolve that name (it doesn't know how). You need to import it as `./path/to/lit-element.js`, which is a path that the browser can resolve.

Comment: @alfredopacino No, i haven't. Are you saying that `import 'lit-element'` works fine?

Comment: There must be an issue in how I'm explaining the problem. `lit-element` doesn't work if you import it in the browser, either by the bare name or by path. I'm wondering why, that's the aim of the question.

Comment: @alfredopacino How does it not work, is there any error? Maybe it doesn't import its own dependencies with path specifiers?

Comment: is there any error? I appreciate you're trying to help, but I have to ask: have you read my question?

Comment: @alfredopacino Your question didn't state that you tried to import the library with a path specifier. If you did, are you still getting the same error? And where exactly is it coming from?

Comment: trying to import it by path the error is on `lit-html` `Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "lit-html". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".` because `lit-element` imports `lit-html` by name

Comment: Yes, the `lit-element` module would need to import its dependencies by path as well for this to work in the browser. Not sure whether there are bundler-like tools that could do this transformation automatically when given the folder structure of modules that you're serving.

Comment: yes. LitElement has its own CLI which transpile the imports, but why someone would use the import by name forcing the user to use a bundler? I cannot see the point..

Comment: Because they don't know on what path `lit-html` is placed in your module-folder structure, and they don't want to reference `lit-html` as an absolute hard-coded path on some CDN.

Comment: the path of the dependencies of a module is a problem every npm modules have. The most logic thing would be assume the npm path, not forcing to use a bundler. Actually now I have a wider doubt: am I supposed to be able to import in browser npm modules or not? Is it a common practice?

Comment: Even npm paths are configurable, so you cannot hardcode it. (And it would be a nightmare for the bundler having to transpile a hardcoded path into something else). No, you are not supposed to simple serve your `/node_modules` folder on the web and import them. The common practice is to use a bundler or dedicated loader (that knows how to resolve imports on your infrastructure).

Comment: Well, in my opinion, bundler should be supposed to be necessary for other tasks, not just for importing modules. Also, there are a lot of npm modules importable in a browser, even pretty big ones (jquery for example).

Comment: @alfredopacino Well jQuery is the exception here, it's a clientside library with no dependencies and their build process spits out one single big module.

Comment: ok, but there are tons of others (mostly are either for frontend usage or very simple indeed). Are you saying there is NO WAY for an npm module WITH external dependencies to be loaded in a browser (without bundler)?

Comment: Yes, unless it hardcodes its dependencies as static paths.